# Firebase unexpectedly persisting anonymous auth, available with onAuthStateChanged

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I've been using Firebase anonymous auth for a React Native app, primarily to ensure users can only read/write their own data (e.g. checking `auth && auth.uid` in security rules)

Previously, with Firebase 2.4.2, my authentication scheme was as follows:

1. user signs up

   ```
   firebaseRef.authAnonymously((error, authData) => {
     if (error) {
       // handle error
     } else {
       // store the token on device
       store(authData.token);
     }
   });
   ```
2. whenever user opens up the app later, create a session with the stored token

   ```
   firebaseRef.authWithCustomToken(storedToken, (error) => {
     if (error) {
       // handle errors
     } else {
       // proceed
     }
   });
   ```

It appears that the token returned by anonymous auth in Firebase 2.4.2 would work for custom auth.

Having upgraded to Firebase 3.1, this flow no longer works -- specifically, attempting to create a `signInWithCustomToken` session with an `signInAnonymously`-generated token returns the error `auth/invalid-custom-token`.

However, the problem of not having a persistent session seems to have gone away. Now, with Firebase 3.1:

1. user signs up

   ```
   firebase.auth().signInAnonymously().then(user => {
     // store token
     user.getToken().then(token => store(token))
   });
   ```
2. whenever user opens up the app later, the session is still available and this listener is called

   ```
   firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
     // user is still authenticated
   });
   ```

It's not clear to me how this is working, how is Firebase persisting the session?

Comment: Is firebase.auth' remembers a user between runs for you?

Comment: @Cherniv yes, the user credentials are stored in async storage as described below in Frank's answer, so that onAuthStateChanged picks it up on reload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On version 2.x of the Firebase JavaScript SDK authentication worked on React Native, but session information was not persisted anywhere between runs. The reason for this is that local storage (which Firebase uses for persisting this information in the browser) is not available in React Native.

In version 3.0 of the Firebase JavaScript SDK authentication did no longer work on React Native.

As of version 3.1 of the Firebase JavaScript SDK authentication works again on React Native. The session details are persisted in [React Native's Async Storage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html).

Comment: Got it, very cool. Since this is anonymous auth (and therefore nothing really can be changed about the auth session, like an email or password), can we expect this session to persist indefinitely?